# Case statement in Vhdl converter

Tags: switch-statement, converters, vhdl

I am new in VHDL language so maybe it is dumb question but I didnt find any reference of this problem.
So, I am working on bit converter which convert specific combinations of 5 bits into other combinations. Problem is with case statement, where I dont know how to put five bits into one contition.

```
entity CONV is
    port (ia, ib, ic, id, ie:in Bit; oa, ob, oc, od, oe:out Bit);
end CONV;

 architecture BEH of CONV is
 signal t: bit;
  begin
  case ia & ib & ic & id & ie is
    when  "00010"  =>  t <= "00011";
    when  "00101"  =>  t <= "00101";
    when  "01000"  =>  t <= "00110";
    when  "01011"  =>  t <= "01001";
    when  "01110"  =>  t <= "01010";     
    when  "10001"  =>  t <= "01100";
    when  "10100"  =>  t <= "10001";
    when  "10111"  =>  t <= "10010";
    when  "11010"  =>  t <= "10100";
    when  "11101"  =>  t <= "11000";
    when  others   =>  t <= "00000";
  end case;
t => oa & ob & oc & od & oe;
  end beh;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
entity CONV is
    port (
        ia, ib, ic, id, ie: in  Bit;
        oa, ob, oc, od, oe: out Bit
    );
end CONV;

architecture BEH of CONV is
    signal t: bit_vector(0 to 4);
    subtype fivebit is bit_vector(0 to 4);
begin
EVALUATE:
    process (ia, ib, ic, id, ie)
    begin
        case fivebit(ia & ib & ic & id & ie) is
            when  "00010"  =>  t <= "00011";
            when  "00101"  =>  t <= "00101";
            when  "01000"  =>  t <= "00110";
            when  "01011"  =>  t <= "01001";
            when  "01110"  =>  t <= "01010";     
            when  "10001"  =>  t <= "01100";
            when  "10100"  =>  t <= "10001";
            when  "10111"  =>  t <= "10010";
            when  "11010"  =>  t <= "10100";
            when  "11101"  =>  t <= "11000";
            when  others   =>  t <= "00000";
        end case;
    end process;
OUTPUT:
    (oa , ob , oc , od , oe) <= t;
end architecture BEH;
```

The expression being evaluated in a case statement must be one of: the name of an object with a locally static subtype (Russell's vector_in), an index name with locally static indexes,  a slice name with a locally static range, a function call that returns a locally static subtype, or a qualified expression or type conversion with a locally static type mark (shown).

The idea being that analyzer (locally static means analysis time) can determine the number of elements in the expression and their type to determine case coverage.

The aggregate target for the concurrent signal assignment associates elements of the aggregate (oa , ob , oc , od , oe) with elements (Bits) of t on the right hand side individually.  Each element association can occur only once.

The case statement is contained in a process (a concurrent statement) because it is a sequential statement.  And to prevent any confusion there are both sequential and concurrent signal assignment statements.  VHDL uses concurrent statements to provide parallelism.

With a test bench:

```
entity conv_test is
end entity;

architecture test of conv_test is
    signal ia, ib, ic, id, ie:      bit;
    signal oa, ob, oc, od, oe:      bit;
    signal t:                       bit_vector (0 to 4);
    signal input:                   bit_vector (0 to 4);
begin
DUT:
    entity work.CONV
        port map (
            ia => ia, ib => ib, ic => ic, id => id, ie => ie,
            oa => oa, ob => ob, oc => oc, od => od, oe => oe
        )
    ;
TEST:
    process
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;  -- bit defaults to '0', others case
        (ia, ib, ic, id, ie) <= bit_vector'("00010");  -- first case
        wait for 10 ns;
        (ia, ib, ic, id, ie) <= bit_vector'("00101"); 
        wait for 10 ns;
        (ia, ib, ic, id, ie) <= bit_vector'("01000"); 
        wait for 10 ns;
        (ia, ib, ic, id, ie) <= bit_vector'("01011"); 
        wait for 10 ns;
        (ia, ib, ic, id, ie) <= bit_vector'("01110"); 
        wait for 10 ns;
        (ia, ib, ic, id, ie) <= bit_vector'("10001"); 
        wait for 10 ns;
        (ia, ib, ic, id, ie) <= bit_vector'("10100"); 
        wait for 10 ns;
        (ia, ib, ic, id, ie) <= bit_vector'("10111"); 
        wait for 10 ns;
        (ia, ib, ic, id, ie) <= bit_vector'("11010"); 
        wait for 10 ns;
        (ia, ib, ic, id, ie) <= bit_vector'("11101"); 
        wait for 10 ns;
        (ia, ib, ic, id, ie) <= bit_vector'("11111"); -- others case
        wait for 10 ns;
        wait;                               -- one time only
    end process;
SIM_INPUT:
    input <= (ia & ib & ic & id & ie); -- for ease of viewing in waveform display
RESULT:
    t <= (oa & ob & oc & od & oe);
end architecture;
```

You can test conv:

[image: test bench waveform output]

Note that the TEST process could be re-written much simpler assigning to input instead of the aggregate (ia, ib, ic, id, ie), by using

```
(ia , ib , ic , id , ie) <= input;
```

in the SIM_INPUT statement:

```
TEST:
    process
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;  -- bit defaults to '0', others case
        input <= "00010";  -- first case
        wait for 10 ns;
        input <= "00101"; 
        wait for 10 ns;
        input <= "01000"; 
        wait for 10 ns;
        input <= "01011"; 
        wait for 10 ns;
        input <= "01110"; 
        wait for 10 ns;
        input <= "10001"; 
        wait for 10 ns;
        input <= "10100"; 
        wait for 10 ns;
        input <= "10111"; 
        wait for 10 ns;
        input <= "11010"; 
        wait for 10 ns;
        input <= "11101"; 
        wait for 10 ns;
        input <= "11111"; -- others case
        wait for 10 ns;
        wait;                               -- one time only
    end process;
SIM_INPUT:
    (ia, ib, ic, id, ie) <= input; -- for ease of viewing in waveform display
```

And get the same waveform display

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
architecture BEH of CONV is
signal vector_in  : bit_vector(4 downto 0);
signal vector_out : bit_vector(4 downto 0);
begin
case vector_in is
  when  "00010"  =>  vector_out <= "00011";
  when  "00101"  =>  vector_out <= "00101";
  when  "01000"  =>  vector_out <= "00110";
  when  "01011"  =>  vector_out <= "01001";
  when  "01110"  =>  vector_out <= "01010";     
  when  "10001"  =>  vector_out <= "01100";
  when  "10100"  =>  vector_out <= "10001";
  when  "10111"  =>  vector_out <= "10010";
  when  "11010"  =>  vector_out <= "10100";
  when  "11101"  =>  vector_out <= "11000";
  when  others   =>  vector_out <= "00000";
end case;

vector_in <= (ia & ib & ic & id & ie);

oa <= vector_out(4);
ob <= vector_out(3);
oc <= vector_out(2); 
od <= vector_out(1); 
oe <= vector_out(0);
```

Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You can put all the inputs into a bit vector like @Russell says. Then each bit in the bit vector represents an input. This makes things much easier.

And *case* statements are sequential statements(i.e. They must be put into a *process* or a *procedure* or a *function*).

```
entity CONV is
  port (inp : in  Bit_Vector(4 downto 0);    -- [ai, bi, ci, di, ei]
        outp: out Bit_Vector(4 downto 0));   -- [ao, bo, co, do, eo]
end CONV;

architecture BEH of CONV is
begin
  process (inp)
  begin           
    case inp is 
      when  "00010"  =>  outp <= "00011";
      when  "00101"  =>  outp <= "00101";
      when  "01000"  =>  outp <= "00110";
      when  "01011"  =>  outp <= "01001";
      when  "01110"  =>  outp <= "01010";     
      when  "10001"  =>  outp <= "01100";
      when  "10100"  =>  outp <= "10001";
      when  "10111"  =>  outp <= "10010";
      when  "11010"  =>  outp <= "10100";
      when  "11101"  =>  outp <= "11000";
      when  others   =>  outp <= "00000";
    end case;
  end process;
end beh;
```

If you really want to use single bits for readablity or other reasons, just concatenate and interrupt them outside the *process*.
For pin planning, all you need is connect `ai` to `inp[4]`, `bi` to `inp[3]` and so on.